# Segue from GameScene to a viewController Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, swift3

I need to make a segue from a GameScene to a UIViewController. My code so far is the following:

In the GameViewController.swift I added:

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            scene.viewController = self
            view.presentScene(scene) 
        }
         ...
```

and in my GameScene.swift I added

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var viewController: UIViewController?

    ...
```

as well as

```
func returnToMainMenu(){

    self.viewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("push", sender: viewController)

}
```

So my problem is that when I state -  scene.viewController = self - I get an error that says "value of type 'SKScene' has no member 'viewController'". What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `viewController` property is declared in `GameScene`, but  when the scene is created it is of type `SKScene`. The simple way to fix it would be to initialise the scene as a `GameScene` then you will have access to the members declared in `GameScene`.

```
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
    // Other code
    scene.viewController = self
}
```

Also, you should try an exit seque when returning to main menu, but that's another topic.

Comment: For the sake of curiosity. What is an exit segue?

Comment: You can read about the exit seque in this SO [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)