# AdMob Rewarded Video in SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, admob

I'm trying to create a rewarded video ad in my **sprite kit** game. I want to add the rewarded video in my **GameScene.swift** class but the problem is that this isn't a `ViewController` but a `SKScene`.

This doesn't work because my **GameScene.swift** isn't a `ViewController`:

```
ad.present(fromRootViewController: self)
```

I've tried many things but nothing worked. Can someone help me please?
Thanks!

(I want to display this rewarded ad when the player dies.)

Comment: You have to present it from the GameViewController. Use notifications to have the SKScene tell the GameViewController to start the video ad

Comment: @Nik I've tried to create functions in the GameViewController and than call the functions in the GameScene but this didn't work. It gave me the same error when it had to call the functions.

Comment: Use notifications to communicate between the scene and view controller. I'll make an answer as soon as I can

Comment: @Nik I'll search a tutorial about notifications and I'll let you know if it worked! Thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: Is it just the communicating between scene and view controller that you're having a problem with? Or is there another issue here?

Comment: Yes it is just communicating between scene and view controller, because I tried to do this code in the GameScene.swift class ad.present(fromRootViewController: self) but the problem is that GameScene isn't a ViewController so 'self' wouldn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Segue from GameScene to a viewController Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40324149/segue-from-gamescene-to-a-viewcontroller-swift-3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `GameViewController`, setup the observer in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.startVideoAd), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "showVideoRewardAd"), object: nil)

}

func startVideoAd() {

// Do something - play video ad

}
```

In this case, whenever this notification is called, the function inside `GameViewController` named `startVideoAd` will be run. Obviously you would want to change the name to the name of your function that you want to be run.

Then, in your `GameScene`, to send the notification, you would run this wherever/whenever you want to run the function inside `GameViewController`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "showVideoRewardAd"), object: nil)
```

Hope this helps!